# jQuery AJAX load not working on a local server

Tags: jquery

im experimenting locally with jQuery and its load() function.
I have this JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img.menu").click(function(){
    $("div#content").load("about.html");
  });
});
```

It references to

```
<td><img id="toolbar" class="menu" src="toolbar/about.png" /></td>
```

and its supposed to load the about.html file that its on the same folder:

```
<p>some text...</p>
```

And it should get loaded at:

```
<div id="content">
<p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Im following [this](http://www.jquery-tutorial.net/ajax/the-load-method/) tutorial

I dont know what im doing wrong but it doesnt get displayed.
Im using jQuery-1.8.0 btw
EDIT: Im following [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax1) code model too, but with html files like the other tutorial

Comment: Any errors on console ? What is not working actually ?

Comment: It just doesnt get showed. Can't find the problem

Comment: Go through it step by step in FireBug. Is about.html in the same directory as this code?

Comment: If you look in firebug/web console, theres a tab called network. When you click the img, a new network response appears, itll show the response

Comment: Yes, its in the same folder, I'll try wuth firebug now

Comment: btw, im developing localy... Is it needed any web server to implement AJAX? Firebug won't let me run at a local file

Comment: Yes, definitely need a server.

Comment: Tried with XAMPP, now it works. Sorry for trobleing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not be running a server.. Remember that theses calls needs a server to run on. Wamp will do. If not try consoling.

Answer (score 0):

try this one instead of `load`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img.menu").click(function(){
    $.get('about.html', function (data) {
         $("div#content").html(data);
    });
  });
});
```